# Bug of Xcode 4.2 in its storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a view controller with bar buttons, and they all created in storyboard. Now I wanna change the bar buttons to a custom view. All work perfectly in the simulator. But the changes of the bar buttons seem not appearing on my iphone 4. Even after I deleting all the bar buttons, they still be there on the iphone 4. It's really disgusting. Anyone can help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your app on your iPhone, do a Product > Clean. Then Build and Run again.

This is standard operation for such thing.

Comment: Project > Clean to Product > Clean

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the app from your iPhone 4 and rebuild it again....I don't think it's really related to storyboard bug....